# How to call external function inside callback in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Calling a external functions in nodejs as we do in javascript so that we can re-use the function but in my case its not working. Why?

I am guessing its working asynchronously in nodejs. How do I fix this? Callbacks? I am new to nodejs.

```
app.get('/googleSyncCallback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  failureRedirect: 'url'
}),

function(req, res) {

  var contacts = new GoogleContacts({
    token: req.token
  });
  var retrievedContacts = '';
  var retrievedContactsArr = [];

  contacts.getContacts(function(err, contacts) {
    contacts.forEach(function(entry) {
      retrievedContacts = {
        contact: {
          "phone": {
            "cell": entry.phoneNumber,
          }
        },
      }
      retrievedContactsArr.push(retrievedContacts);
      console.log('array... ', retrievedContactsArr[0]); //prints all values
    });
  });
  checkIfContactExists(req, res, retrievedContactsArr);
}
});

function checkIfContactExists(req, res, retrievedContactsArr) {
  //PRINTS UNDEFINED..
  console.log('array... ', retrievedContactsArr[0]); //// LINE 10
}
```

printing the array `retrievedContactsArr[0]` is returning  undefined at line 10.

Comment: The asynchronous behavior you have here is not unique to node, it is standard in the javascript language across platforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @nem035 No usually this works in javascript. Its not working in nodejs only

Comment: is contacts.getContacts an async function?

Comment: @nem035 its a npm package for google contacts: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-contacts

Comment: *in nodejs as we do in javascript* — Node.js is to JavaScript as Firefox is to JavaScript. It is just a way to run JavaScript. The language works in exactly the same way.

Comment: Sorry my friend, but this code will not work on any platform. The reason is that you're trying to access an asynchronous result in a synchronous manner. In other words, you're requesting the contacts from google but trying to use them before they arrive. Check out the attached suggested duplicate for many solutions to this

Comment: Yes. You use a callback. You are already using a callback. You just put `checkIfContactExists(req, res, retrievedContactsArr);` one line too low. You closed the callback function before that line instead of after it. (Voting to close as typo).

Comment: @nem035 But I am calling the function only after retrieving the contacts. I placed it outside of `getContacts` function

Comment: @Satyadev that is the exact problem :). It should be inside. The callback inside `getContacts` gets called **after** you receive the contacts but the line after `getContacts` gets called immediately. I highly suggest you look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for clarification.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks Quentin for your observation. Thank you

Comment: I have experienced similar problems before. Sometimes the browser will execute code synchronously even though it should be asynchronous. I would consider this behaviour an optimization and unreliable -- meaning don't count on it.

Comment: @nem035 okay I will look at it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your function inside the callback, you also need to add a callback to the function, as express can define middleware with the signature (req, res) that must run synchronously or return a promise or have the signature (req, res, next) where next is a callback.

```
app.get('/googleSyncCallback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  failureRedirect: 'url'
}),

function(req, res, next) {

  var contacts = new GoogleContacts({
    token: req.token
  });
  var retrievedContacts = '';
  var retrievedContactsArr = [];

  contacts.getContacts(function(err, contacts) {
    contacts.forEach(function(entry) {
      retrievedContacts = {
        contact: {
          "phone": {
            "cell": entry.phoneNumber,
          }
        },
      }
      retrievedContactsArr.push(retrievedContacts);
      console.log('array... ', retrievedContactsArr[0]);
      checkIfContactExists(req, res, retrievedContactsArr);
      next()
    });
  });
      
    }
    });

    function checkIfContactExists(req, res, retrievedContactsArr) {
      //PRINTS UNDEFINED..
      console.log('array... ', retrievedContactsArr[0]); //// LINE 10
    }
```